# Azure DataFactory concurrency

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a custom Dotnet activity which I am running via ADF which basically connects to Azure Blob storage , get lease for a blob it parses. Although I am setting concurrency to 10 in my settings and I see 10 jobs running in parallel on the UI , I see only 4 locks on my blobs(only 4 blobs are leased and parse in process). Therefore it is my assumption that although the other 6 jobs are running, they are not doing anything? Are there any constraints on concurrency in ADF?I am starting 10 of my previous slices, so I don't have to wait 15 min for future slices to start.Is this an ADF concurrency bug where at most 4 run at a time or am I doing something wrong.

Appreicate any help!

Answer (score 1):

One constraint I can think of and which could be limiting the number of concurrent slice executions is the `maxTasksPerNode` property of batch pool in your batch account, by which you specify maximum tasks per node in pool. This value can be max 4x the number of node cores.

Here's some additional reding on the topic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-parallel-node-tasks#enable-parallel-task-execution